# Ubuntu install Junit

Tags: java, ubuntu, junit

I am trying to install Junit on Ubuntu. I have gotten Java to work so that I can compile java files. However, junit is giving me problems (cannot get the base test cases to work to prove installation worked correctly).

Here is what I did:

```
sudo apt-get install junit
```

Now when I type `which junit` it gives me `/usr/bin/junit`

Similarly, through another stack exchange post, I found that my junit.tar file
is here:

```
/usr/share/java/junit.jar
```

I added the path to the junit.jar file to my CLASSPATH and since the website (http://junit.org/junit4/faq.html#started_2)
says "make sure that the JUnit installation directory is on your CLASSPATH"

I added the second path above to my CLASSPATH in .bashrc

so when I run `echo $CLASSPATH`:
I get `/usr/share/java/junit.jar:/usr/bin`

However, then when I try to run `java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore org.junit.tests.AllTests`

in order to test that I have installed and configured JUnit correctly, I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.junit.runner.JUnitCore 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
```

I am very much a beginner and am just learning Ubuntu, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You normally don install Java libraries like that. You use Maven or Gradle and specify the dependencies of a project, which will automatically download them during the build. Also most ways of executing or compiling Java applications ignore the CLASSPATH environment variable.

Comment: Also, are you sure that apt-get didn't install some ancient version of JUnit, which doesn't contain `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore`? For example, JUnit 3.x doesn't contain any `org.junit.*` packages

Comment: Given that the Ubuntu repository has both `junit` and `junit4`, I'd say changes are high it is an ancient version. However, stop using apt-get to install Java libraries. Learn to use Maven or gradle, or manual download the appropriate jars from the project website, and get in the habit of explicitly specifying classpaths on the commandline, instead of relying on `CLASSPATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful comments and answer, I will definitely look into these options as I move forward!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you have installed JUnit 3.8 (see https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/junit). And JUnit 3.8 doesn't contain any packages `org.junit.*`, as these were introduced in JUnit 4. In theory you could fix this by installing the package [`junit4`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/junit4) using `apt-get` (which will install JUnit 4.12).

But this is the wrong approach, you should learn how to use Maven or Gradle (or both), which will automatically download dependencies for you, and take away some of the chore of compiling (granted, in exchange for a bit higher learning curve).

Alternatively, if you really want to do this manually, get in the habit of downloading dependencies from project websites, and explicitly specifying the classpath during compilation and execution. Relying on system package managers for this is the wrong approach (wrong versions, different version requirements between applications/projects, libraries not in the repository, etc). Relying on the `CLASSPATH` environment variable is very brittle (wrong versions, unexpected effects of having libraries on the classpath etc), and as most ways of executing Java applications don't even use it, it is the wrong thing to learn.

TLDR, really, you should learn the basics of Maven or Gradle.

Answer (score -1):

As Mark mentioned in the comments, use Gradle to manage your packages. In IntelliJ go to your `build.gradle` for your app. Within the dependencies object add the following

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```